# how to render different components on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have several buttons on my UI and on click I want to load the corresponding components to them using react, I don't know how to do that.

Earlier I was doing this using ternary operator but that only works for two components, here I am having more than two components.

I have 5 buttons on click of each I am hitting my back-end And then render the content on UI.

[Please check the code sandbox for all code](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-oskar-8qit2?file=/src/App.js)

On click of buttons I have to render the components and those have different UIs If all were having same data format and same UI I could have done this with useState but here needs to load the components

Comment: @ParthS007 no I don't want to create rout on each click, it would be a bad idia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have some mistakes in your components `User, Admin and Client`: they have the same names in files.
You can easily solve your problem like that:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Buttons from "./Components/side_btns";
import { Admin, Client, User } from "./Components";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("");

  const onSideBtnClick = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setActiveTab(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-5 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
          <Buttons trigerOnClickEmpSideBtn={onSideBtnClick} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-7 col-sm-7 col-md-9 col-lg-10 col-xl-10" />
        {activeTab === "admin" && <Admin />}
        {activeTab === "user" && <User />}
        {activeTab === "info" && <Client />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-shape-fi2xl?file=/src/App.js:0-853).

Answer (score 1):

I just used a dictionary approach to render the components using the button value. You can check [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-mendeleev-5m0xp?file=/src/App.js).

```
const dynamicComponents = () => {
  const components = {
    admin: <Admin />,
    info: <Client />,
    user: <User />
  };

  return components[componentName];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

keep the state of tabactive and switch between them like:

```
          {tabactive == 1 ? (
            <Admin />
          ) : tabactive == 2 ? (
            <User  />
          ) : tabactive == 3 ? (
            <Security />
          ) : tabactive == 4 ? (
            <Profile />
          ) : null}
```